# JLabels not showing in JPanel if bounds not set

Tags: java, swing

I have the following code:

```
public JPanel getPanel() {
    if(jpanel == null) {

        jpanel = new JPanel();
        jpanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jpanel.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        jpanel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        JLabel tituloLbl = new JLabel(titulo);
        JLabel cantidadLbl = new JLabel(""+cantidad);
        JLabel abejasLbl = new JLabel("Abejas");

        //tituloLbl.setBounds(0, 0, 50, 15);

        jpanel.add(tituloLbl);          
        jpanel.add(cantidadLbl);
        jpanel.add(abejasLbl);      


    }
    return jpanel;
}
```

The panel should look like a small white box with 3 labels in it, however, the labels don't show unless I set their bounds. Why does this happen? If I'm setting a FlowLayout, the labels should be positioned automatically.

This is how the panel shows:

[image]

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. We don't know anything about the window in which you display this panel, so we can't really help.

Comment: @RealSkeptic nvm, just got it solved. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, I had to call panel.validate() on my main frame in order to show them.

Comment: That should be revalidate() which is the Swing method.